# Sum result of a query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add result of another query, but i can not

In the image is the result of the first query.
Now I need to add this result and group by date

[image: Example in Image]

Example:
  200 + 200 + 199 + 199 + 199 + 200 .... = Result

my code:

```
 SELECT SUM (
(SELECT 
    [DATA],
    IIF((
            Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1 - COALESCE(LAG(Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1) OVER (ORDER BY Icas.COD_ICAS), 0)) > 0 
            AND (Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1 - COALESCE(LAG(Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1) OVER ( ORDER BY Icas.COD_ICAS),0)) < 500, 
            (Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1 - COALESCE(LAG(Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1) OVER (ORDER BY Icas.COD_ICAS), 0)), 0) AS DifL1
    FROM VW_ICAS Icas )) AS Res
FROM
    VW_ICAS
GROUP BY
    [DATA]
```

[image: Result of my query]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post images of code, data and error messages; they are all text and should be provided (at least) as formatted `text`. The error you have posted isn't in English either, and since we can't copy and paste it, those that don't speak the language have no idea what it says. Stack Overflow is an English speaking website, so please ensure you provide questions, answers and comments in English. I suggest taking the time to correct your question. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at your query, however, your subquery returns 2 columns, which you're trying to aggregate on. `SUM` can only aggregate on a single column.

Comment: Sorry, i'm starter, follow text Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Não é possível executar uma função de agregação numa expressão com um agregado ou uma subconsulta.

Comment: Take the time to fix your questions @xKunky. Users don't always read the comments and your error should be in your question, not the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do aggregates on columns, not on results. Your solution could go 2 different ways. One is to aggregate on DATA

```
SELECT 
    [DATA],
    SUM (IIF((
            Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1 - COALESCE(LAG(Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1) OVER (ORDER BY Icas.COD_ICAS), 0)) > 0 
            AND (Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1 - COALESCE(LAG(Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1) OVER ( ORDER BY Icas.COD_ICAS),0)) < 500, 
            (Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1 - COALESCE(LAG(Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1) OVER (ORDER BY Icas.COD_ICAS), 0)), 0)) AS DifL1
FROM VW_ICAS Icas 
GROUP BY [DATA];
```

Or you could simply get the SUM of all rows in a resultset by converting it to a derived table, but still referencing a column.

```
SELECT SUM(DifL1) AS SUMDifL1
FROM(
    SELECT 
        [DATA],
        IIF((
                Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1 - COALESCE(LAG(Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1) OVER (ORDER BY Icas.COD_ICAS), 0)) > 0 
                AND (Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1 - COALESCE(LAG(Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1) OVER ( ORDER BY Icas.COD_ICAS),0)) < 500, 
                (Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1 - COALESCE(LAG(Icas.CONTADOR_ICAS_1) OVER (ORDER BY Icas.COD_ICAS), 0)), 0) AS DifL1
    FROM VW_ICAS Icas )x;
```

Comment: with few changes, i completed my query! Thanks bro, you do our days more happy!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this query gives the data you provide in your image:

```
SELECT [DATA], IIF(...) AS DifL1
FROM VW_ICAS Icas
```

(I truncated the expression for `DifL1` for clarity.)

And you want to do this with that data:

```
SELECT [DATA], SUM(DifL1)
FROM [the result above]
GROUP BY [DATA]
```

You can put the first query into the second one as a table expression:

```
SELECT [DATA], SUM(DifL1)
FROM (SELECT [DATA], IIF(...) AS DifL1
      FROM VW_ICAS Icas) AS X
GROUP BY [DATA]
```

This should work, I guess.

It's a variant of the second query of @LuisCazares's answer, but with a grouping on field [DATA].